# 'Server Not Found' error when using sfDomainRoutePlugin with Symfony

Tags: apache, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I am trying to create a site with subdomains, using the [sfDomainRoutePlugin plugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDomainRoutePlugin). I am using SF version 1.4.12 on Linux, with Apache as the web server.

I am following the online instructions and have created the following routing file:

```
homepage:
  url:          /
  class:        sfDomainRoute
  param:        { module: foo, action: index }
  requirements:
    sf_host:    [portal.localhost]

#Sample route limited to one subdomain
blog:
  url:          /
  class:        sfDomainRoute
  param:        { module: foo, action: foo1 }
  requirements:
    sf_host:    blog.portal.localhost

#Sample route that will capture the subdomain name as a parameter
user_page:
  url:          /
  class:        sfDomainRoute
  param:        { module: foo, action: foo2 }

#Sample route that will not receive a subdomain and will default to www.greenanysite.com
install:
  url:          /install
  class:        sfDomainRoute
  param:        { module: foo, action: foo3 }
```

My foo module code has the methods foo1, foo2 and foo3 implemented as stub functions, and each have their template which simply contains text confirming which method was executed (e.g. 'foo::Foo1 was called') etc.

The template for the index method (in the foo module) looks like this:

```
<html>
  <head><title>Test subdomains</title></head>
  <body>
    <ul>
        <li><?php echo link_to('homepage', '@homepage'); ?></li>
        <li><?php echo link_to('blog', '@blog'); ?></li>
        <li><?php echo link_to('zzzrbyte', '@user_page?subdomain=zzzrbyte'); ?></li>
        <li><?php echo link_to('install', '@install'); ?></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

The urls are generated correctly (i.e. with subdomains as specified in the routing.yml file), however when I click on the 'blog' or 'zzzrbyte' link, I get the error message: **'Server Not Found'**

For example, I got this message:

> Server not found Firefox can't find the server at
>   blog.portal.localhost.

AFAICT, I am following the online instructions exactly, so I can't see where I am going wrong. Can anyone spot what is likely to be causing this problem?.

**[[UPDATE]]**

I just realized that by adding the subdomain to my hosts file, this seems to get rid of the problem. I am not sure if this is the fix or simply a temporary workaround. If this is the way to do things, I wonder why such a vital piece of information was left out of the notes?

If this is the way to get things to work, it means that subdomains will have to be known before hand (i.e. not generated dynamically and resolved at run time), also - I am not sure how such a solution works for a remote server, since I am running multiple websites (as virtual servers) on one physical machine and I am not using a hosts file on the server.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the subdomain to the hosts is the correct way to solve this issue